# Do local versions of postgres foreign data wrappers update automatically?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

Apologies if this is answered in the docs or somewhere else obvious, but I have just gone through the rigmorale of having to use `postgres_fdw` to get data from another database (quite different to the ease of MS SQL!)

I ran an `IMPORT SCHEMA` statement to get the foreign table/databse data into my working database. Will the data in this schema automatially update whenever the data in the foreign database updates or is this `IMPORT SCHEMA` a copy of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign table does not contain any data. Querying it will yield the current data in the remote table. Think of it as something like a view.

If you are talking about metadata changes (`ALTER TABLE`), the analogy to views is also helpful: such changes will not be reflected in the foreign table, and you need to run an `ALTER FOREIGN TABLE` statement.

Perhaps it would make sense to put the data for these databases in a single database in two different schemas.